# How Can I build a C++ class in Php Extension?

Tags: php, c++

I'm trying to wrap c++ class in a php Extension.Using this http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/ link, and also I created a module for php extension.After that I have to compile  a C++ class in a php extension.How can I do that???

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [the series by Sara Goleman](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/) that is also referenced in the [Zend DevZone article you linked](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/).
There, you'll find everything you need, including examples you can follow before writing your own extension.

Also, the PHP documentation has a [chapter about writing extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php).

Comment: Could you please elaborate and rephrase your question? I don't know what you want.